# Python: I got TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, I don't know how to fix it after a google search

Tags: python

I might be being dumb, but I'm not sure why I got this error.

The code:

```
  loggedin = fetchData3()
  accounts = fetchData2()
  logusername = loggedin["username"]
  
  for account in accounts:
    if account["username"] == logusername:
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 184, in <module>
    logusername = loggedin["username"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: What part about this is unclear?

Comment: do `print(loggedin)`, you'll see it is a list and so you can't access some "username" prop

Comment: I can't get how people can be coding, and have absolutly not thought of debugging or at least trying to, by just printing variable that solves 95% of issues

Comment: output:[{'username': 't', 'Password': 't'}]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting `loggedin` to be a dict/map but it is in fact a list. As the own error mentions you can only access lists by using integers or slices.

Review `fetchData3()` and `fetchData2()` functions because they are returning as output a list instead of a map.

Comment: From your last comment, you can see that `fetchData` functions are returning a map encapsulated in a list of just one element. Then, you can access to the map by just doing `loggedin[0]["username"]`.

Answer (score 0):

List can be accessed using Indexes or Slicing. Use loggedin[0] to access the first element in the list and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetchData3() function is returning a list and you are calling it like a dict.

```
loggedin["username"]
```

Figure out what fetchData3() is returning and you will figure out your problem.  But also, looking up that type error basically anywhere on the internet would tell you that you are trying to access a list element with a string index.  Google could have told you everything I just did.